# WPF - Resizing chromeless windows using attached behaviors,..Any suggestions?

Tags: c#, wpf, interop, resize, attachedbehaviors

Who fancies a challenge?

I'm currently working on the `ControlTemplate` for a chromeless `Window` which will be a part of a reusable theme assembly.  I want the behaviors for moving, closing, minimizing and restoring to be implicit so I've written attached behaviors for this functionality which I've then included in the template.

Now,..I've come to resizing and I've come to a junction.  For better or worse I'm handling the mouse move in the behavior and finding whether the cursor is inside the resizing 'zones'.  I'm far enough to change the cursor appropriately but now I've gotten to actually resizing the window there are three options I've come across.

I could hand-ball the affair and adjust the Left & Top and Width & Height as needed.  This is the simplest option and is easily achievable using attached behaviors but it seems like moderately heavy lifting and I understand that WPF will continue to render as the window is adjusted causing flickering,..which sucks.

The second option is to get a message hook and listen for WM_NCHITTEST and the like but the solutions I've found so far involve me sub-classing `Window` and I don't want to force consumers of the theme to use any controls that aren't framework provided.

The last option is to somehow draw a rectangle on the screen showing the are the `Window` will take up as the mouse is dragged and then resize on `MouseUp`,..which seems doable but it's not something I've done before so some pointers on that would be cool.

So,..what should I do?  The Win32 route seems like my best option so far but I'd rather not if someone has a 'purer' solution that works.  I'm happy to get suggestions with option 3 and anything right up to .Net 4 in case some `dynamic` magic might be possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Pete Brown has the answer.](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/02/01/moving-a-wpf-window-with-custom-chrome)

Comment: No he doesn't.  That article is just moving a window using DragMove in an event handler...which doesn't answer the question I asked at all.

Comment: Damn, you're right. And I probably came to this post back then looking for this too! If you find the right code, let me know please. :)

Comment: After some research I found the best thing is to use the shell integration library found at - http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell